# Text-processing only for conditions met from line X to Y

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

How can we delete duplicate lines only seen in lines X to Y and change the file in-place?

For instance, if I just want to delete duplicate lines from line 10 to 20.

Comment: are the targeted lines already sorted, and if not, can they be as a result?

Comment: duplicates within 10-20 lines or trough all file?

Comment: I'm confused. Your comment on sjsam's answer indicates duplicates just within lines 10-20, but your latest comment says the duplicates can exist anywhere in the file.

Comment: @Costas sorry I meant only lines 10-20. But I have 5 files and I want all duplicates between line 10-20 be deleted.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry, I made mistake, edited my answer to Costas.

Comment: @JeffSchaller No they are not sorted. I just want all duplicate lines from 10th line to 20th be deleted.

Comment: @ParsaX to avoid misunderstanding better to provide the sample of input and desired output

Comment: @Costas Yes, you're right, but I wanted a pattern so I can be able to run on all 5 files of mine. Stéphane's answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `awk` (4.1.0 or above for the `inplace` extension¹):

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '
  NR >= 10 && NR <= 20 {
    if ($0 in seen) next
    seen[$0]
  }
  {print}' ./file
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -ni -e 'print if $. < 10 or $. > 20 or !$seen{$_}++' ./file
```

To process several files:

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '
  BEGINFILE{delete seen}
  FNR >= 10 && FNR <= 20 {
    if ($0 in seen) next
    seen[$0]
  }
  {print}' ./*.txt
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -ni -e '
  print if $. < 10 or $. > 20 or !$seen{$_}++;
  if (eof) {close ARGV; undef %seen}' ./*.txt
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is your friend

```
awk '{
      if(NR>=10 && NR<=20)
      {
        if($0 in record){
         next
        }else{
         print;
         record[$0];
        }
     }
     else{
        print
     }
     }' file > temp && mv temp file
```

Comment: Indentation makes scripts more readable.   Also the `{if(` and `)` are not needed on the first line (the `NR>=10 && NR<=20` "pattern" is still required).    `awk` scripts consist of a series of *pattern {action};* statements, either of which are optional ("pattern" defaults to true ("condition" would probably be a better name for it than "pattern"), and "action" defaults to print`).

Answer (score 2):

If OP need to remove lines which duplicates just within 10-20 lines:

```
sed -i '
    :a; 10,19!b; N; s/\(^\|\n\)\([^\n]*\)\n\(\(.\+\n\|\)\2$\)/\1\3/; ba
       ' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: It gives the wrong result on the output of `printf '%s\n' {1..10} T TEST` for instance. It also assumes GNU `sed` (and that `POSIXLY_CORRECT` be not in the environment)..

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are write. Have change regexp.

Answer (score 1):

The very same tricks applied in the Perl-based answers can also be used to shorten the Awk code, and it ends up smaller and cleaner:

```
awk 'NR < 10 || NR > 20 || !seen[$0]++'
   ^ ^          ^           ^
   | |          |           |
   | \__________\___________\______ no sigil noise
   |
   \_ no options here to remember
      (unless we want that Gawk inplace semantics)
```

The counters will not overflow because the range is restricted to ten lines—and GNU Awk has bignum integers anyway.